# Commenting tool/library

Tags: java, jquery, comments

I developed web based application (spring+hibernate+jQuery) that
contains articles. I need some tool/plugin/framework/library to organise
comments these articles by users of this application. 
I searched the internet and found only one
http://www.9lessons.info/2011/05/facebook-wall-script-with-php-and.html
It use jQuery+PHP.

Please, help with other tools on Java+jQuery

Best regards, Pavel

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for comment management then you should take a look at:

http://disqus.com/

http://www.livefyre.com/

Comment: I need component that I can implement in my app